# How to return multiple results from an array of options?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of data :

```
$ary = new array(
    array("domain"=>"domain1", "username"=>"username1"),
    array("domain"=>"domain1", "username"=>"username2"),
    array("domain"=>"domain2", "username"=>"username3"),
);
```

I need to use this data to retrieve data from a MySql database with the following table structure (simplified for illustration).

```
domain_table
    domain_id
    domain

user_table
    user_id
    user

stuff_table
    stuff_id
    ... details

link_table
    link_id
    user_id   -- The user we are searching for connections on
    connected_user_id   -- from the array above
    stuff_id
```

I need to fetch every row in the stuff table for a single user_id that also has a connected_user_id from the array.

I'm using PDO

There may be hundreds (possibly thousands) of entries in $ary.

I could generate a very large query by looping thorugh the array and adding loads of joins.
I could perform a single query for each row in $ary.
I could create a temporary table with $ary and use a join.
Something else?

What is the best way - fastest processor time without being too arcane -  to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. *perform a single query for each row* - bed way because of small speed
2. many joins better then 1.
3. if it is possible - make view & use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your entire dataset is HUGE and doesn't fit in memory, joins shouldn't be your choice.

Do sequential selects. Select rows from your link_table, gather user_id's out of the result in PHP. Then select rows from user_table using "where user_id in (?)". Handle grouping of results in PHP.

Even with large tables selects by key will be fast. And having 2-5 selects instead of 1 select is not a problem.

Joins will be fast while your DB fits into RAM. Then problems arise.

Comment: RE: joins. Is this true even if all joins are on primary keys?